# four people fall into a giant amoeba

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to get title of a short story from the 40's or 50's where four people from a repressive earth society land on an alien planet, fall into a giant amoeba like alien, two of them fight the other two for freedom rather than return to earth. By Tenn? or Kuttner?

Comment: "four people fall into a giant amoeba" ... sounds like start of a joke.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The story is ["Four in One"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46235) by [Damon Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damon_Knight). [This blog post](http://variety-sf.blogspot.fr/2009/10/damon-knight-four-in-one-novelette-how.html) has a summary that matches your description. You can read the story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v05n05_1953-02.Galaxy/Galaxy%20v05n05%20%281953-02.Galaxy%29#page/n5/mode/2up).